# Securely store pictures on share for use in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

Lets say we have photographers who use one computer in a department. They take pictures of an event then upload and organize pictures in an application. That application by default takes someone's shared location and copies pictures to that share.

On a web server there is a share we point it to. We want to make it so ONLY that application can access that share, and only THAT web application (of course, anyone with admin login to the physical server can).

Also make it so that any web browser can display the image (I believe Firefox can't take a file location of `\\server\share`)

Logically it would look like this:

1. Photographer uses an application on a public computer
2. Application copies images to share
3. Web application uses images (cross browser)
4. No user from public computer can access those images  EDIT: the displaying on the webpage is not the problem, its how I store files in the webroot securely, so that my app can SHOW the images that are located within a shared location in a webroot. Allowing only the application on a terminal computer to access that share and NOT the user running the application from that computer. I.e. a person cant just run a command and download the entire directory contents from wherever he wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait, what? You want to show the users some pictures in a browser, but don't allow them to download them? That's impossible.

Comment: No, I want them only to be able to see the images from the webpage. I don't want the ability for anyone on the terminal computer to be able to view the folder that the web server gets those images from. Ever seen the facebook movie? I don't want somebody able to wget all my files in my share directory and misuse pictures people have entrusted to me.

Comment: Well, then you'd have to go with a solution like @Adam Tuliper proposed. Let only your asp.net application access the files on the share (and deny all other users access), and create a page like `photo.asp?id=123`, which then looks for `photo123.jpg` on the share, reads it, and passes its data to the visitor.

Comment: That would still be pretty easy to loop through HttpRequests and increment ID up by one each time grabbing every picture on the webserver.

Comment: Then you randomize the ID, like a GUID or an MD5 hash of the filename plus a predetermined salt.

Answer (score 0):

Simply configure your share's permissions (ie right click on it) to be limited to a certain windows user. Run your application under that windows user so it will have access to that share. Done!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a service account and run/impersonate your web and desktop applications with the 
   service account
2. Share the pictures (located on the shared drive) for the service account so that no other
   user can access